# Is there a good list of accidental Lie algebra isomorphisms?

Tags: lie-algebras

The Wikipedia page [Exceptional isomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_isomorphism) contains some lie algebra isomorphisms. Is there a list more complete than that, especially including real algebras in low dimensions?

Comment: There is [a similar question on MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81344/exceptional-isomorphisms-of-lie-groups)